# What's the easiest way to change polarity of the output of an op-amp-based voltage amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Can I simply swap the input lines of the op-amp (that is, 2 connects to +, 3 connects to -) shown in the figure below to change the output signal polarity?

[image]

Comment: You cannot just wap the + & - terminals of the opamp because the feedback has to be always negative. You can use the inverting opamp configuration and adjust the resistor values

Comment: @sai you are right. If you can draw an inverting configuration in an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a non-inverting configuration with gain of 11. The following is the inverting configuration with a gain of 11.

[image]

I assume you are using +5V single supply for the opamp. The purpose of the potentiometer on the + terminal of the opamp is to set an appropriate output DC value so that when the pulse occurs, the output voltage does not get clipped to 0V because -ve voltages are not possible for single supply opamp.

There are 2 differences between the non-inverting and the inverting configurations that we need to address:

1. The bias voltage across the SPIM will be lesser because the -ve terminal of the opamp will not be at 0V. It is at some +ve voltage which is equal to that on the +ve terminal set by the potentiometer. May be you need to adjust +HV to compensate for this if the change in bias voltage is not acceptable.
2. Since we changed the resistor values of R3, R6, I am not sure how it impacts the value of C2. If C2 is for stability, you need to figure out the value of C2 needed for stability with the new resistor values.

**Edit: Option2: SIPM leakage to ground**

You could use the following option if you want the leakage from the diode to flow to the ground. This also addresses point no.1 & 2 that I mentioned above.
[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Now, the problem is that the detector, SiPM, has large leakage current. In the original design, the leakage current can go to the ground. Can we find a way to guide it to the ground in the new design? Sorry that I did not mention this in the original post.

Comment: @Jing, I have added option 2 where the leakage current is into the ground.